# Compounds that vary water's superheated and supercritical limits

Tags: physical-chemistry, water

Are there any compounds that reduce water's sensitivity to extreme heat change and/or volatility to high heat (over 800 degrees Fahrenheit), whether organic or inorganic?

Comment: Please read the tag wikis before putting tags like "computational-chemistry" on your post, this is a completely unrelated question.